# Possible to Manipulate Chrome app "webview" dom with javascript/jquery/AngularJS or some otherway

Tags: javascript, jquery, webview, angularjs, google-chrome-app

Hello Fellow Stack Over Flow Geniuses.  I hope I have what i hope is a simple question.  I am creating a packaged app and have access to data that I do not need to necessarily parse with JavaScript but would like to re represent the data in a new way from a very plain Jane view. To something more acceptable

So my question is:

is it possible to access the dom of "Web View"( Chromes packaged app answer to Iframe)  with java script or jquery or Angular and manipulate just the look and feel of the data being projected in that IFrame( Web View) ?

Any sample code would greatly be appreciated.

If the above question does not make sense I have provided a more elaborate explanation here ** Ignore If You Don't Care Why I Am Setting It Up This Way **:

I have a page that uses ajax to update a list of information dynamically for some internal systems. Each system essentially just spits out data in no organized fashion. The information supplied is very... well... how do I put it.... bland haha.  The goal is to one remove this from the browser side view so another tab is not open; while keeping the functionality and integrity of the data intact server side.  I need for my team specifically to be able to access/manipulate the view of data locally only and provide essentially a easier view of the data being provided and manipulate another way. This is to ensure data can be reformatted per department without affecting everyone's view of the data as everyone uses it differently.

I have done ajax pulls and have parsed data and requires many calls to be made to refresh the data where this is already being done server side. I feel it would be easier to just load the page live through the web form and manipulate the data from there to display how and where I want it.

Any recommendations on how to easily accomplish this task would also be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call executeScript in a WebView:

```
var wv = document.querySelector('webview');
wv.executeScript({code: "document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';"})
```

Although this is not the most practical way of doing what you need. If possible, I would rather convince the server side developers to generate a JSON feed of the data and having your Packaged App XHR'ing it in and formatting it appropriately.

**UPDATE**: if you only need to reformat the Webview content, you can also use the simpler [`insertCSS`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-insertCSS) method:

```
var wv = document.querySelector('webview');
wv.insertCSS({code: "body { background-color: black;}"})
```

Comment: unfortunately i do not have access to the mysql php portion of the system to print out json as this would be an ideal solution.  But I do appreciate the code above as this is exactly what I needed thank you!

Comment: Hey @mangini, any news options here? Injecting script to drive form filling is quite painful.

Comment: In fact, the question was about webview content re-format, not form filling. I've updated the answer to include the insertCSS method, which is a much simpler way of doing it (at the time of the original answer, insertCSS wasn't available to Chrome Apps).